# How do I bundle webpack 2 for development?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I'm working on a personal project and have set up my webpack config.

However I want to have both a production config and a dev config where I can step through my un-minified files on the browser and hit my debuggers.

So far it seems like my webpack config is stripping all my debuggers and I can't the files are minified so I can't set manual breakpoints either

Comment: There seems to be a general problem with hitting breakpoints with Webpack 2 ... .